# How to replace all values (by a function) in nested list in Python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

There are many suggestions but I can't make it stick. The closest solution I have below. The data is like:

```
my_list = ([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6 , [], [8, 9]], 10]], 8)
```

and a function

```
def convert(G, l, d):
    z = []
    if isinstance(x, list):
        print(x)
        z.append(convert(G, x, d))
    else:
        print(x)
        z.append([v[d] for n,v in G.nodes(data=True) if n == l])
    return z
```

execution:

```
print(convert(G, my_list, "name"))
```

It gives empty array but print(x) gets the source as is. I'm close I guess. The problem is I don't know how to pass `l` at `if n == l` as a integer not list.

**EDIT**

Outpit:
`(['a', ['b', 'c'], 'd', ['e', ['f' , [], ['g', 'h']], 'j']], 'g)`
in the same format (nested). The custom function just takes each element (int) and returns its attribute from dict (letter).

Another try:

```
my_list = ([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6 , [], [8, 9]], 10]], 8)
z = []
def convert(G, l, d):
    z.append([convert(G, x, d) if isinstance(x, list) else [v[d] for n,v in G.nodes(data=True) if n == x]])
    return z

z = convert(G, my_`list, "name")
print(z)
```

This part is a custom function:

```
[v[d] for n,v in G.nodes(data=True) if n == l]
```

so G can be whatever. You can take it as `[...]`

For example: `G.nodes = {0: {'name': 'a'}, 1: {'name': 'b'}, 2: {'name': 'c'}, 3: {'name': 'd'}}`

Comment: what's your expected outcome for the given data?

Comment: Can you make sure you've included an [mcve]? For example, what's `G`? As @Peter.k mentioned, what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: So you want a `map` function for nested lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a kind of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function that works for nested lists. Try this:

```
def deepmap(f, lst):
    return [deepmap(f, x) if isinstance(x, list) else f(x) for x in lst]
```

This will convert the outer `tuple` to another `list`, though. If you need that to be a tuple, or if there can be more tuples within, it should not be too hard to extend that function accordingly. Example:

```
>>> my_list = ([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6 , [], [8, 9]], 10]], 8)
>>> deepmap(str, my_list)
[['1', ['2', '3'], '4', ['5', ['6', [], ['8', '9']], '10']], '8']
```

In your case, the mapping function `f` might be something like this, not entirely sure though. (You might also want to change your `G.nodes` data structure so you don't have to iterate all the items but can access item `x` directly.)

```
f = lambda x: next(v[d] for n,v in G.nodes(data=True) if n == x)
```

Comment: Yes. This solution works as well. Just needed to pass `d` argument to `deepmap` and `lambda` the rest is as is.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version, following your structure, might look like this:

```
def v(x):
    return x + 1

def convert(l):
    z = []
    for x in l:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            z.append(convert(x))
        else:
            z.append(v(x))
    return z
```

This results in the expected nesting:

```
>>> convert([[1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6 , [], [8, 9]], 10]], 8])
[[2, [3, 4], 5, [6, [7, [], [9, 10]], 11]], 9]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. This is oke. I forgot to iterate `for x in l:`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom mapper

```
import string
def mapper(item):
    if not isinstance(item,list):
        return d[item]
    else:
        return [mapper(i) for i in item]

d=dict(zip(range(1, len(string.ascii_lowercase) + 1), string.ascii_lowercase))
```

Mapping dict will look like this

> {1: 'a',  2: 'b',  3: 'c',  4: 'd',  5: 'e',  6: 'f',  7: 'g',  8:
>   'h',  9: 'i',  10: 'j',  11: 'k',  12: 'l',  13: 'm',  14: 'n',  15:
>   'o',  16: 'p',  17: 'q',  18: 'r',  19: 's',  20: 't',  21: 'u',  22:
>   'v',  23: 'w',  24: 'x',  25: 'y',  26: 'z'}

```
my_list = ([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6 , [], [8, 9]], 10]], 8)
tuple([mapper(i) for i in my_list])
```

You can also use `map` function with custom mapper

```
tuple(map(mapper,my_list))
```

Output

```
(['a', ['b', 'c'], 'd', ['e', ['f', [], ['h', 'i']], 'j']], 'h')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a recursive function to do the convert:

```
my_list = ([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6 , [], [8, 9]], 10]], 8)
mapping = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j'}

def convert(inlist):
    def transform(x):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            return convert(x)
        else:
            return mapping.get(x)
    return [transform(x) for x in inlist]
print(convert(my_list))
```